# how to click button in python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

```
<div class="gift">
    <button type="button" data-log-actionid-label="gift" data-log-body="{&quot;current_product_no&quot; : &quot;1003072802&quot;, &quot;group_product_no&quot; : &quot;&quot;, &quot;group_product_firstview_no&quot; : &quot;&quot;, &quot;product_price&quot; : &quot;5600&quot;, &quot;send_impression&quot;: &quot;Y&quot;}" data-is-send-log="true">
        togift
        <span class="ic_new">new</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Can't use by text, because this page have lots of text **`togift`**

How can I click this button ?

Comment: Is `class="ic_new"` unique?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `class name`:

```
div = driver.find_element_by_class_name('gift')
btn = div.find_element_by_xpath('.//button')
btn.click()
```

If there are other tags with the same class name, then you can use the `css selector` or the `full xpath`

Answer (score 0):

Should click on the div class gift with button.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("div[class='gift']/button").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not enough html source to let us know how to write a correct and short element's location statement.
So just try the below `xpath expressions`:

```
"//div[@class='gift']/button[contains(text(),'togift') and ./span[contains(text(),'new')]]"
"//div[@class='gift']/button[contains(text(),'togift')]"
"//div[@class='gift']/button"
```